Android soft keyboard is missing "OK" button after upgrading Unity from 2020 to 2022 LTS
Just upgraded Unity from 2020.3.48f1 to 2022.3.35f1 and immediately regretted it. I have a lot of input text fields in my project (TMP_InputField), some of them are single line and some multiline, that's why it's so important for my project that multiline inputs must have that "OK" button above the soft keyboard, cause at the right bottom corner there is a break button for multiline fields. If the field is single line, there is a "Done" button at the right bottom corner, it's fine. But if it's multiline - there is no way for users anymore to finish typing and close soft keyboard. That's why i am searching how to fix this new problem.

There was ok in Unity 2020.3.48f1 and all input fields (no matter single or multiline) were with "OK" button. Now i can't downgrade to older Unity version and can't figure out how to get this button back.
Interesting, that my secondary Android device with Android 10 still showing "OK" button, but devices on Android 13 is missing it. What should i do in this situation? There are no such settings in TMP input field in Unity.
Also the only post about this problem i found on Unity Issue Tracker
Maybe there is any way to turn "Ok" button via code in Unity? I don't even know what to do. This is a real problem for my app now...
I'm searching for this situation already for 3 days and can't find any solution and any information except Unity Issue Tracker (link in description).

On Unity's version 2020.3.48f1 was the "OK" button available for Android 13? Because this might be an issue with how the device's os is dealing with text input.
Also @derHugo is an expert on Unity, he might be able to help you.

Yes, it was for sure always available on all known Android versions before i switched to higher Unity version :(
